# Form input-box not displaying

Tags: python, django, forms, amazon-web-services, input

I'm trying to display a simple form input-text box with Django. I'm am deploying on Amazon AWS. The site works fine on a different server (pythonanywhere) but there is a major problem on AWS. Specifically, the input box is not being displayed. I'm using templates as follows:

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'lists/base.html' %}

{% block header_text %}Start a new To-Do list {% endblock %}

{% block form_action %}{% url 'new_list' %}{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>To-Do lists</title>
        <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 jumbotron">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1>{% block header_text %}{% endblock %}</h1>
                        <form method="POST" action="{% block form_action %}{% endblock %}">
                            {{ form.text }}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% if form.errors %}
                                <div class = "form-group has-error">
                                    <span class = "help-block">{{ form.text.errors }}</span>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    {% block table %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django

.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class List(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_list', args=[self.id])

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default = '')
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, default = None)
    #list = models.ForeignKey(List , default=None)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from lists.models import Item

EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR = "You can't have an empty list item"
class ItemForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('text',)
        widgets ={
            'text' : forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
                    'placeholder': 'Enter a to-do item',
                    'class': 'form-control input-lg',
            }),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'text' : { 'required': EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR }
        }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from lists.models import Item, List
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from lists.forms import ItemForm
from lists.models import Item, List

# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'lists/home.html', {'form': ItemForm()})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from lists import views

urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^new$', views.new_list, name='new_list'),
                url(r'^(\d+)/$', views.view_list, name='view_list'),

        ]
```

Currently the site displays the following:

[image]

However it should (and does on a different website) display this: [image]

I've pushed/pulled the entire project to github and the code between each site is identical, yet I'm not seeing why the text input isn't displayed, unless the form needs to be initialized in Django somehow or a quirk to AWS?

When comparing the two sites, the one without the text-box does not generate the following:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="id_text" name="text" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" type="text" />
```

Even though it should, per the **base.html** syntax.

*Updated*

The full **views.py** (per suggested comment) is:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from lists.models import Item, List
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from lists.forms import ItemForm
from lists.models import Item, List

# Create your views here.
def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'lists/home.html', {'form': ItemForm()})

def new_list(request):
    form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        list_ = List.objects.create()
        Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['text'], list=list_)
        return redirect(list_)
    else:
        return render(request, 'lists/home.html', {"form": form})

def view_list(request, list_id):
    list_ = List.objects.get(id=list_id)
    form = ItemForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['text'], list=list_)
            return redirect(list_)
    return render(request, 'lists/list.html', {'list': list_, "form": form})
```

Comment: Have you tried running `./manage.py collectstatic`? It is the first thing I try when I am having issues with templates, especially on the server.

Comment: The `home_page` view is not being used anywhere in the URL definitions that you have posted...?

Comment: @elethan - Yes, I've run collectstatic thanks. I'm able to see changes to the templates and collectstatic to see them effect the page, but the form updates no luck. I have noticed that on pythonanywhere when I make changes to forms.py I have to run the 'reload' function on that website, which I think might reload the server and see the effects of form changes? Because if I change the forms.py without this change, I also don't see the changes there either.

Comment: @solarissmoke - Yes thanks, I've added the full views.py which is referenced in the urls.py

Comment: @Jeeves ah, yes. I had this issue as well on both pythonanywhere and digitalocean. I have never used AWS, but I would imagine the same thing is necessary there. If you have ssh access to your server, try running `sudo reboot now` from the command line and then checking again (or however you reboot an AWS instance)

Comment: @elethan - Thanks! That worked! I kept trying : sudo service reload. I figured it had to do with the server reloading somehow.

Comment: @Jeeves great! If you don't mind, I will rephrase this as an answer so that future users can find the solution easily.

Comment: @elethan - Yes, I meant to mention you should do that. I'll lock it as answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience with Django, there are 2 things you often (always?) need to do to get static files to "refresh" after pushing them to a remote server:

1. Run `./manage.py collectstatic` to make sure all your static files are in the right place.
2. While `ssh`ed into your server run the command `sudo reboot now` to restart your server (note that this will kick you out of your ssh session, and your server will be unreachable for a moment - usually just a few seconds in my case).

As for step **2** there might be a better way to do this, but in my experience, when I update static files the updated version is not served until I do this, and restarting `nginx` or the like is not sufficient for the changes to take effect. Note that this will mean that your site, if live, will not be reachable for a few seconds while the server is restarting (which is what makes me think there might be a better way to do it) but for me and my small user base this is not a big issue.

From reading some other posts about static files not updating, it seems like it could also be the case that your browser is caching the static files, and that restarting your browser/clearing the cache might do the trick as well, but I have not had a chance to try this yet.