# django css setup not working

Tags: html, css, django

I followed some tips from related questions in here, and tried the documentation but failed so far to get css file working.

Note that css (obviously) works perfectly fine if I place it within the template, but I can't import it from static folder.

So in my app folder, I created a static folder, within which I created another folder called static: app->static->style.css

When I run collectstatic, it gets style.css, and places it in: projectfolder->static->style.css

All of this is working fine.

My static settings were set automatically, I changed it based on some answers I read in related questions, but still didn't work:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = u'/home/user/projectfolder/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = u'/home/user/projectfolder/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my template, I have:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
....
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css" />
....
```

Clearly I'm missing something, when I reload the website, no css is shown. In my css I have clearly set the body background to test it, but it doesn't change.

Extra info:
- Debug is set to true
- Using the latest Django version .10

Any help or direction would be appreciated,

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing this locally or on a server? I assume locally because of your DEBUG setting, but wanted to double check. Also try changing your href to `"{% static 'myapp/style.css' %}"` where `myapp` is the app name of course.

Comment: @elethan This is done on a server, I tried "{% static 'myapp/style.css' %}" and it didn't work, then I tried "{% static 'style.css' %}" and it worked. Thanks mate, place it as an answer and I will choose it as correct. Thanks again :) Please leave a little explanation for others who might be facing the same problem.

Comment: you might as well accept the posted answer if you are satisfied with it, and I will not bother posting my own. Glad you got things sorted! Also, since you are talking about a Django site on a remote server, be aware that when you update static files there, the changes will not always be immediately visible on your live site. I have gotten tripped up by this a few times, and recently answered a question about this here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126082/3642398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you view the page's source code from what path is it trying to load your style?

Try this - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "style.css" %}" />`

Also I would change MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT to `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`. This way both paths are being built by the system and it's harder to mess up.

Comment: I edited the question, it wasn't app->static->app->style.css, rather it was app->static->style.css. I took elethan's advice and it worked. I will also consider your advice and change the media_root and static_root. Thanks.